# Was PEview developed using Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I was checking [PEview.exe](http://wjradburn.com/software/) image section headers and I didn't find the .txt section, but i found code section instead, it means it was developed using Delphi, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope ... Here's the environement used to develop it [GoDevTool](http://www.godevtool.com/). Given what I read about the GoDevTool, it looks it might have been written in 32bit Windows assembly which was interfaced with a Go API.